# can't impliment firmware from command

Tags: wireless, networking, command-line

Forgive my ignorance of command line utility, as I'm new to Ubuntu

Actually I have to install a Tool already developed for WiFi application which give output of received packets.

In that process i have modified the kernel as required and NEXT STEP is to install their customized firmware.

```
# step 1
# backup original firmware, good for reference
sudo cp /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-5000-2.ucode /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-5000-2.ucode.orig
sudo mv /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode.orig

# step 2
# copy ours in separately, keeping name for reference
sudo cp iwlwifi-5000-2.ucode.sigcomm2010 /lib/firmware/

# install ours
sudo cp iwlwifi-5000-2.ucode.sigcomm2010 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-5000-2.ucode
```

But in step 2, all I get is "No such File or Directory" can anyone explain actually what I have to do in this step?

As far as I understand in first step I made a copy of original firmware by changing its name, and then I'm trying to replace the customized code instead of original BUT I CANT..!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's trying to copy a file named `iwlwifi-5000-2.ucode.sigcomm2010` from the *current directory* to `/lib/firmware/`. If you're not in the same directory as this `iwlwifi-5000-2.ucode.sigcomm2010` file (or haven't even downloaded it, etc, etc) you need to get it and `cd` into the same place or specify the path:

```
sudo cp /path/to/iwlwifi-5000-2.ucode.sigcomm2010 /lib/firmware/
```

Comment: What about sudo cp iwlwifi-5000-2.ucode.sigcomm2010 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-5000-2.ucode Will it replace iwlwifi-5000-2.ucode with iwlwifi-5000-2.ucode.sigcomm2010??